# tryCatch - withCallingHandlers - recover from error

Tags: r

I have a csv file (aprox 1000 lines) with some sample data.  while reading the csv with read.table

```
  read.table(csv_File,header = FALSE, sep=",",na.strings = '')
```

I was getting an error,

```
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
    line 515 did not have 5 elements
```

Is there any way, by using tryCatch and withCallingHandlers, to print this error message and continue with the rest of the file?

all I am expecting is to get error messages/ stack trace in case of errors and process the rest of the lines in csv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as far as I know there's no way to get `read.table` to skip lines that contain errors.  What you should do is use the `count.fields` function to find how many fields are in each line of your file, then read the whole file, delete the bad lines, and read again.  For example:

```
fields <- count.fields(csv_File, sep = ",")
bad <- fields != 5
lines <- readLines(csv_File)

# At this point you could display the bad lines or
# give some other information about them.

# Then delete them and read again:

lines <- lines[!bad]
f <- tempfile()
writeLines(lines, f)
read.table(f, header = FALSE, sep=",", na.strings = '')
unlink(f)
```

EDITED to add:

I should mention that the `readr` package does a better job when files contain problems.  If you use

```
library(readr)
read_csv(csv_File, col_names = FALSE)
```

it will produce a "tibble" instead of a data frame, but otherwise should do what you want.  Each line that has problems will be reported, and the overall problems will be kept with the dataset in case you want to examine them later.